# Is it possible to automatically run a cmd command when I open a particular folder in VS code?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, cmd, configuration-files

So I am working on a project where I have activate a python virtual environment in the cmd terminal so when I heard about task in vs i tried to implement it. But almost all I found was related to npm task. Since i need the command to run from that file location I cannot figure it out

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Activate virt",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "virt/Scripts/activate.bat",
            "windows": {
                "command": "virt/Scripts/activate.bat"
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen",
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "cd to Test Project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd TestProject",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cd TestProject"
            },,
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is basically what I tried and I need to these two commands to run one after the other.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: So are those two commands running on folderOpen?

Comment: Yes these two commands shoud run one after other once i open that folder

Comment: Are you using iPython? If so, use the `jupyter.runStartupCommands` setting.

Answer (score 0):

You would make a third task that runs the other two, see [Compound Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks)

```
{
  "label": "Build",           // whatever name you want
  "dependsOn": ["Task 1", "Task 2"],
  "dependsOrder": "sequence",
  "runOptions": {
     "runOn": "folderOpen"
  }
}
```

Then remove the `runOptions` from each of the other two tasks.  And the `Build` task will first run those two tasks on folder open in the sequence indicated by `dependsOn`.